# Vehicle Routing - Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, traveling-salesman

I am tweaking Vehicle Routing Problem to cater our business needs using the provided Optaplanner example.

Capacity = Total number of hours available to a vehicle in a day(X hours)

Demand = Time to move to a Customer + Serving Time at Customer's location

The problems I'm facing -

```
Scheduling should be done on day to day basis with new Customer orders added and removed dynamically. How to do?
(Assumption - Customer orders will be available before scheduling but new Customer order might come while scheduling)

How to reset the Capacity? (Every other day vehicles are renewed with X hours. Every other day vehicles will have X hours available again.)

Vehicle may not need to return to the Depot at the end of the day and can start from the Last Customer location to get to new Customer another day.

What if the vehicle consumes all it's available hours during the transit before reaching the Customers location? Will it result in ageing for that particular customer?
```

Any insights about any of the problems mentioned above are appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too general in my opinion. I think you might join the optaplanner forum for an opinion discussion. In SO you discuss about technical usage of optaplanner.

Comment: thanks @the.wizard. I will do as suggested and see if I can get some insights regarding the same.